# Sync with multiple databases

Tags: pouchdb

How do you use sync in case there are 10 databases.

Do I have to set up 10 new sync?

```
db = new PouchDB(this.database);

db.sync(remoteCouch, opts1)
db.sync(remoteCouch, opts2)
...
```

Which means it will open 10 different http connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. In that case, you may want to avoid using live replication so you don't keep 10 HTTP connections open. (I.e. just replicate one-at-a-time.)

Or you can replicate from the 10 PouchDBs to a single in-memory PouchDB and then replicate from that to CouchDB (if your databases can fit in memory).

Comment: Does it mean, that if I had 100 different dbs (for example using per-share "strategy", different database for different sharings like shared with-mary-john, etc), than this is the only way also?

Comment: Yes, there's a global changes feed across all databases (thus allowing for one single HTTP connection), but it's in CouchDB 2.0 and therefore upcoming, not currently available.

Comment: thank you. Btw any chance to know when 2.0 will be released?

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but you might be able to get the necessary global changes feed before 2.0, using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/couchdb-global-changes

Comment: can i use setInterval  instead live sync?multiple database does not sync in live