# Handle multiple remote databases pouchdb

Tags: ionic2, pouchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to build an ionic2 application which syncs data from cloudant, i want to be able to sync data from multiples remote databases with pouchdb.

Any solutions?

Comment: Please describe what you tried and what didn't work. This question is too broad to answer.

Comment: I'm trying to duplicate this line and change museums to users  this.remote = 'https://oussemalaamiri.cloudant.com/museums/';

Comment: That is still too little context for me. Sorry. Could you post parts of your code and perhaps error messages?

Comment: i want to know if pouchdb allow multiples instance of databases,that's my problem,i didn't tried nothing yet.

Comment: Did you look at this anwser? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011848/pouchdb-multiple-remote-databases-single-local-database-fancy-replication

Comment: not very helpfull,here is my code                                                       
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';@Injectable()
export class Todos { data: any;
  db: any;
  remote: any;
  username: any; password: any;constructor() {  this.db = new PouchDB('cloudo');
this.db = new PouchDB('cloudo');
 this.username = 'xxxxx';
    this.password = 'xxxxx';
    this.remote = 'https://oussemalaamiri.cloudant.com/museums/';
  let options = {
      live: true,
      retry: true, continuous: true, auth: {username: this.username,  password: this.password
      }